# Having trouble with this method of changing and showing a new window in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having quite the trouble using classes in python. The first code I used in changing and showing a new window works but too cluttered so i decided to use the class. but there might be something wrong in my code. Can you atleast see to it? Thank you. Hoping for a fast response.

```
import random, sys, os, rabinMiller, cryptomath
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        #frame1.title("RSA Cryptosystem")
        #frame1.config(bg="black")
        container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, DecryptionPage, EncryptionPage, MakeKeyPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        image4 = Image.open("rsa cryptosystem logo.jpg")
        photo4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, image=photo4)
        label1.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        label1.image = photo4
        image1 = Image.open("MAKE KEY.jpg")
        photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        image2 = Image.open("encryption button.jpg")
        photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
        image3 = Image.open("decryption button.jpg")
        photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, compound=TOP, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MakeKeyPage), width=338, height=338, image=photo1)
        button1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=S, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        button1.image = photo1
        button2 = tk.Button(self, compound=TOP, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(EncryptionPage), width=525, height=150, image=photo2)
        button2.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        button2.image = photo2
        button3 = tk.Button(self, compound=TOP, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DecryptionPage), width=525, height=150, image=photo3)
        button3.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        button3.image = photo3

class DecryptionPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        textframe1 = tk.Text(self, width=70, height=32).grid(column=3, row=2, rowspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(S, E))
        image5 = Image.open("INSERT PRIVATE KEY.jpg")
        photo5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)
        image6 = Image.open("INSERT ENCRYPTED TEXT.jpg")
        photo6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image6)
        image7 = Image.open("DECRYPT.jpg")
        photo7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image7)

        button4 = tk.Button(self, width=338, height=80, image=photo5, command=open_file)
        button4.grid(column=1, row=2,columnspan=2, sticky=N)
        button4.image = photo5
        button5 = tk.Button(self, width=338, height=80, image=photo6, command=open_file)
        button5.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
        button5.image = photo6
        button6 = tk.Button(self, text="BACK", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button6.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        button7 = tk.Button(self, width=338, height=338, image=photo7)
        button7.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky=S)
        button7.image = photo7

class EncryptionPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        textframe2 = tk.Text(self, width=70, height=32).grid(column=3, row=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(S, E))
        image8 = Image.open("INSERT PUBLIC KEY.jpg")
        photo8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image8)
        image9 = Image.open("ENCRYPT.jpg")
        photo9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image9)

        button8 = tk.Button(self, width=338, height=80, image=photo8, command=open_file)
        button8.grid(column=1, row=2,columnspan=2, sticky=N)
        button8.image = photo8
        button10 = tk.Button(self, text="BACK", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button10.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        button9 = tk.Button(self, width=338, height=338, image=photo9)
        button9.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky=S)
        button9.image = photo9

        receivename = StringVar()
        receivename_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=85, textvariable=receivename).grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(W, E))
        label4 = tk.Label(self, text="TO: ").grid(column=3, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)


class MakeKeyPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        keyname = StringVar()
        phone = StringVar()
        keyname_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=keyname)
        keyname_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Key Name: ")
        label2.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Key Type: ")
        label3.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
        button12 = tk.Button(self, text="BACK", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

        prime = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Prime", variable=phone, value='prime').grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
        luckyprime = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Lucky Prime", variable=phone, value='luckyprime').grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
        button11 = tk.Button(self, text="Generate Keys").grid(column=1, row=5, columnspan=2, sticky=(W, E))



app = MainFrame()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: your code isn't properly formatted.

Comment: Sorry about that sir Bryan. Here, I have edited it so that the format is correct i guess.

Comment: what is the problem you're having? Do you get errors? What errors? Does it behave in a way that you don't expect? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: I am having errors. Only the "window" is created with no widgets in it.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\ttk interface 3 revised.py", line 120, in <module>
    app = MainFrame()
  File "C:\Python34\ttk interface 3 revised.py", line 20, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:\Python34\ttk interface 3 revised.py", line 58, in __init__
    textframe1 = tk.Text(self, width=70, height=32).grid(column=3, row=2, rowspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(S, E))

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2961, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2115, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2093, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'DecryptionPage' object has no attribute 'tk'